# Implement IDropTarget

Tags: c++, drag-and-drop, c++builder, c++builder-2009

I would like to drag and drop files from windows explorer onto my application which is being built in Codegear RAD studio 2009. Then I would like to be able to access data from the object I am dragging and dropping. I believe I have to implement IDropTarget. Can someone please provide an example of how I might implement IDropTarget to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [nice example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide6.aspx) written by Michael Dunn over at codeproject.com which shows how to implement `IDropTarget` and access data from inside a `IDataObject` which is used to store data during the drag and drop operation.

Comment: Thanks. That link got me started. I also found another two links which eventually helped me achieve the result I needed.

http://bcbcaq.freeservers.com/project_DD.html - this is an example implementation of implementing IDragDrop in BCB

https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?messageID=90402&#90402 - this helped me provide a way to determine which specific control the item was being dropped on.