# ActiveX: Get values from ActiveX

Tags: c#, asp.net, activex

I have ActiveX control which helps me to drag and drop desktop and outlook attachments into ActiveX control, I have implemented this on my ASP.NET Webpage which gets dropped items to the control, now i want to access those dropped items/files into the ActiveX control. How to access items from ActiveX control?

Here is my ActiveX

```
<object id="Draggable" height="200" width="350" classid="CLSID:D43D0F1F-785F-472F-9845- 195A769D56A8" codebase="Draggable.DLL">
    </object>
```

Note:

1. Security is not a concern for me since we are using it only on our intranet.
2. We are not going to use HTML5

Comment: It depends on what language/framework you used to create your ActiveX control, maybe you should clarify that.

Comment: I am using Windows Control Library control to create an ActiveX, i am able to get items dropped to activeX.

Comment: You mean [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxczf775(v=vs.80).aspx)?

Comment: Anyway, you'd need to [implement IDropTarget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176050/implement-idroptarget) on your control.